# Matrix summation

Tags: matrix-equations

$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 1
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a \\
b
\end{array} \right)
%
=
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
3 - X \\
6 - X
\end{array} \right)
$

Can anyone please verify if  my answer is correct:

$a = 1-0.66X$

$b = 1+0.32X$

Comment: You can use WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix equation $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3-X\\6-X\end{bmatrix}$

is equivalent to the system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}a+2b=3-X\\ 2a+b=6-X\end{cases}$$

Taking twice the second line and subtracting the first implies the equation: $2(2a+b)-(a+2b)=2(6-X)-(3-X)$, or simplified $3a = 9-X$.  In other words, $a=3-\frac{1}{3}X$

Do so similarly for finding $b$.

Comment: JMoravitz:  b = -0.33X Could you please confirm?

Comment: @flyhigh1 and how did you come upon that?  Did you do like I did and take the equations in the implied system and combined them?  You should have done twice the first equation minus the second equation to get $2(a+2b)-(2a+b)=2(3-x)-(6-x)$ to get $3b = -x$.  Note that $\frac{1}{3}$ is **not** the same thing as $0.33$.  If you are doing work in mathematical contexts, be *exact* with numbers, don't round unless explicitly told to or unless completely unavoidable.  $0.33=\frac{33}{100}\neq \frac{33}{99}=\frac{1}{3}$